# How to calculate the points for a 60 degree triangle

Tags: geometry

Given are two points on a line with coordinates.  How do we calculate the third forming a perfect 60 degree triangle?  So we have X,Y, but need Z...

X: 0,0      ( 0,0 i.e. horizontal, vertical )
Y: 50, 0 
Z: 25, ??

How to calculate the missing horizontal coordinate for Z? Forming a perfect 60 degree triangle?

EDIT:
I'm trying to figure out a formula that by providing only 50 as the length of one side of the triangle all the point coordinates can be figured out.  The first 2 and half of them are easy (0,0 50, 0, ??, 25)... but how to calculate the number at '??' is what I'm trying to figure out.

EDIT2 (@Dennis):
It would probably help if I explained that my coordinates are not of the actual point but a 100px wide circle that the point is in the middle of.  I made a small video to show you guys exactly what I'm doing and will post is just as soon as it's done uploading.

EDIT3:
Here is a video showing exactly what I mean and why I came up with the question in the first place:  http://archebian.org/videos/math/triangle-question.mp4

Comment: Show some effort please. Add an illustration of the coordinates on the plane. Describe your thoughts on the problem and where you got stuck. This is not a 'do my homework for free' service!

Comment: Lol I'm not asking for home work help smart guy.

Comment: Take the midpoint of the line joining the two given points, draw a perpendicular to this line and intersect it with $\;y=25\;$ . Why this works?

Comment: @DonAntonio - You are correct, but what I need to do is make this into a formula.  Provide the length of one side and calculate the rest from only that.

Comment: @OB7DEV "Rofl" But it really looks like one... Nevertheless it is really hard to help you, when you don't tell, what you have already tried and where you got stuck. See: http://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Use the properties of an [equilateral triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equilateral_triangle).

Comment: Also see here your question already answered more general: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/92836/point-of-an-equilateral-triangle?rq=1

Comment: @OB7DEV You asked "**How** to calculate the third vertex?", and that's what I addressed and answered. If you read carefully, taking the midpoint between the origin and $\;(50,0)\;$ gives you, of course, the answer to your very last question.

Comment: It certainly can't be $\;25\;$ as ordinate of the third vertex to get an equilateral triangle...

Comment: @DonAntonio - But I'm not drawing actually drawing this on paper with a straight edge and compass

Comment: @OB7DEV It doesn't matter if you **actually** draw or not: in an equilateral triangle all the medians are also heights and angle bisectors, and because of this taking the midoint works.

Comment: @DonAntonio You are right, he just mixed up the second and first coordinate. Z has coordinates (25,*) where * is to be calculated...

Comment: @DonAntonio -Your correct again about 25, see EDIT2

Comment: Hold on everybody: I'm beginning to suspect strongly the OP did **not** mean an equilateral triangle but merely a triangle with **some** angle equal to $\;60^\circ\;$ . This happens sometimes with sloppy questions...

Comment: @DonAntonio - No sir, I did intend it as an "equilateral triangle"... I just didn't know that's what they where called until now!  Thanks for teaching me that!

Comment: @OB7DEV The sloppiness in your question is not for the wrong name but for not even stating **where** in the triangle the angle of $\;60^\circ\;$ is going to be...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### With the video explanation

You are asking for the intersection of two circles (this is **not** creating an *equilateral* triangle). You can take the equations of your circles $c_1: x^2+y^2=50^2$ and $c_2: (x-50)^2+y^2=50^2$.

$$x = \frac{d^2-r^2+R^2}{2d}$$
For your question the distance between the center points is $d=50$ and $r=R=50$. And surprisingly you'll find it at 25. This you can put into the circle equation again and find $$y=\sqrt{50^2 - 25^2}\approx 43,30127$$ Just as in your picture.

You find the solution here: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Circle-CircleIntersection.html.

### For the equilateral part

What about the height of an equilateral triangle being $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}a$ where $a$ is the length of your side. With this you should see that 25 isn't suitable for your chosen height of 25.

e.g. (0,0); (50,0); (25,21.65) is close to perfect. In your post I see the 25 in the y coordinate, which doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: Thanks, I fixed the coordinate mistake in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I gave your question to Pythagoras (a friend of mine): He said: the missing horizontal coordinate is given by

$$ \sqrt{50^2+25^2}.$$

OOps !

Edit: coordinate is given by

$$ \sqrt{50^2-25^2}.$$

Comment: Are you sure that number is the missing abscissa of the third vertex with ordinate $\;y=25\;$ ? We have that $\;\sqrt{50^2+25^2}>50\;$ and thus the resulting triangle would have an angle greater than $\;90^\circ\;$, and of course won't be equilateral. Am I missing something?

Comment: Thanks ! I meant $ \sqrt{50^2-25^2}$ and not $ \sqrt{50^2+25^2}.$

Comment: @Fr That could be, unless the OP meant *equilateral*...but right now I've no *real* idea what the OP meant. Read last comments below question.

Comment: @Fred - You got answers and humor!